# rbenv: having 32 & 64 bit versions of ruby installed side by side on same machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rbenv

For certain reasons (Oracle, I'm looking at you) I need to be able to use 32 and 64 bit versions of ruby.  Can I have both 32 & 64 bit versions of 1.9.3 installed side by side with rbenv? How would I be able to tell them apart when I run rbenv versions?

Right now I'm using a 32 bit version of 1.9.2 and a 64 bit version of 1.9.3. I would much prefer to have a 64 & 32 bit version 1.9.3.

UPDATE:

For now I've just chosen to use a different patch. There has to be a better way...

UPDATE 2:

To clarify my situation, I'm using a machine that runs on Mac OSX Lion.

[this link describes my main problem, no 64bit instant client for Lion](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2318019)

[This link shows the only solution I've found to the problem](http://code.duffy.jp/how-to-use-oracle-with-ruby-on-lion-and-ruby-1-8-7/)

UPDATE 3:

This is no longer an issue, because oracle released [a 64 bit instant client that works on Lion and Mountian Lion](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html).

Comment: I don't see how it could influence anything. The runtime is the implementation for the ruby language. the code should work on either. can you specify more exactly why you need both? *because AFAIK you can just use 64 bit*

Comment: oracle instant client does not have a working 64 bit version that runs on lion or mountain lion. Thus, the ruby oci gem will only work with a 32 bit version of ruby.

Comment: In that case you don't need a 32 bit version of ruby, you need a 32 bit version of whatever libraries oci calls. The ruby implementation has nothing to do with this.

Comment: ... Have you tested that hypothesis? A 64 bit version of ruby will not properly create c extensions for oci with a 32 bit version of instant client in all my trials.

Comment: No, however I did 10 minutes worth of google research.

Comment: Can you point me to any references?

Or are you just being snarky and rude?

Comment: [link 1](http://appsintheopen.com/posts/12-installing-ruby-oci8-on-64-bit-windows) [link 2](http://blog.rayapps.com/2009/09/06/how-to-setup-ruby-and-oracle-instant-client-on-snow-leopard/) [link3](http://www.dixis.com/?p=138), these are the 1st few pages that seem relevant in the search

Comment: Just realized you didn't have any info as to why I have to do what I'm doing. I added a couple links to the question. I have a Mac that runs lion. Those links were for snow leopard and windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have as many arbitrary builds of Ruby installed in rbenv. It doesn't care as long you give them each a uniquely named directory/symlink in `${RBENV_ROOT}/versions/`.

By default, it seems that Rubies built on OS X are 64bit. If you can figure out how to configure 32bit build of Ruby, you could install one with `PREFIX="$(rbenv root)/versions/1.9.3-p194-32"`, for example. Then you can use that version as any other:

```
RBENV_VERSION=1.9.3-p194-32 ruby -v
```

Here I used "-32" prefix to tell versions apart.

Comment: I was doing this until oracle finally released a version of instant client that works on lion & mountain lion. Finally, no more 32bit rubies on this machine!